# Help Wiring PSC Motor

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to wire a PSC motor for use outside of a washing machine. I need some help identifying the wiring and where the capacitor should go.

The model is WH20X10063 and I attached the only documentation I could find for it. I believe this is a reversible model since it has 5 wires, but I only need it to run in one direction. So I shouldn't need all the relays listed in the schematic. The wire colors are red, orange, yellow, violet, and blue, with the resistance values below.

R-V = 5.6 Ohm - auxiliary winding?
O-Y = .1 - ?

O-B = 2.2 - main winding?

Y-B = 2.2 - main winding? but with two, is one reverse?

I think the capacitor goes between the red and yellow wires. I think orange is the overload switch and doesn't need to be hooked up. I think violet might be neutral. I'm not sure what blue is, maybe speed control.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about electronics rather than home improvement (sorry)

Comment: Is it possible to migrate question?